# Vue Leaflet Setting custom TileLayer bounds

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, frontend

I'm trying to display a large number of images using leaflet and I'm having problems making the tileLayers display properly.

I'm extending the TileLayer class and overriding the createTile function like this:
`

```
let imageLayer = TileLayer.extend({
          createTile: function (coords, done) {
            const image = window.L.DomUtil.create("img");
            image.src = `http://placekitten.com/g/200/300`;
            image.crossOrigin = "";
            image.onload = function () {
              this.onload = function () {};
              done(null, image);
            };
            return image;
          }
        });
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdiaM.png)

I want to change the position of the images and to only display them in areas I have already defined (for example between offsetting the image at 0,0 to be at 1,1 or using latLng
`([8273.300000000001, 10618.02] , [9232.653535353536, 9658.666464646465])`).

Ive tried a bunch of different methods and almost always came back to bounds, which don't work and setting the bounds doesn't change anything.

**I don't want to use ImageOverlays because the images I'm trying to display are sliced and named with the leaflet naming scheme (0_0_1.png).**

Comment: Check the `maxBounds` option of `TileLayer`.

Comment: @IvanSanchez how do I check that? I forgot to mention that im creating a new const tile with the imageLayer class, checking tile.maxBounds returns undefined

Comment: By "check" I mean "read the docs", specifically https://leafletjs.com/reference#tilelayer-bounds

Comment: What am i supposed to see in the documentation?? I read it like 14 times today only